# How to find approximate roots of a cubic inequality, Gr 12 advanced functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find the roots of a cubic inequality when none of the roots are real and are decimals?
The question is $x^3+x^2-3x-1\leq0$.

I tried factoring out but nothing worked and when I looked at the answer it showed all the numbers being decimals, but it didn't show how to get them.

So how do I find the roots when there are no real roots?

The exact problem is ". Solve each polynomial inequality by fi rst
fi nding the approximate zeros of the related
polynomial function. Round answers to two
decimal places. c)$x^3+x^2-3x-1\leq0$."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking for how to find the roots or how to find the real number closest to the roots? If you want to find the complex roots then you can use the usual procedure; there are no surprises. If you want to find the real roots that would serve as the best approximants then some sort of interpolation method in $\mathbb{R}^n$ may be necessary.

Comment: all three roots are real numbers. They are not, of course, **rational.**  The bad news is that this is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis#Solution_in_non-real_radicals      Sometimes there are nice trig expressions, but not this time; your discriminant is not a square integer, and the Galois group is not cyclic

Comment: in case you reported the cubic incorrectly: the roots of $x^3 - 3x + 1$  are $2 \cos \left( \frac{2 \pi}{9} \right), \; \; 2 \cos \left( \frac{4 \pi}{9} \right), \; \; 2 \cos \left( \frac{8 \pi}{9} \right), \; \; $

Comment: Note that the question only asks for *approximate* values of roots; for these, you can use [Sturm sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem).

Comment: And FYI - any odd-degree polynomial with a positive leading coefficient goes to $-\infty$ as $x$ goes to $-\infty$ and goes to $+\infty$ as $x$ goes to $+\infty$. So they have no choice but to pass through $y = 0$ somewhere in the middle. If the leading coefficient is negative, that just flips the whole picture. They still have to cross $y = 0$ somewhere. All odd-degree real polynomials have *at least* one real root.